# Unable to add "beforeinstallprompt" to window in Angular2

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I've started my first PWA in angular and i'm trying to show a Popup for Androdi devices which will tell the user to press on the button to install it.

The iOS part works well, i'm shiwing a popup which explain how to install the PWA while the android part where i have to add the beforeinstallprompt listener not working.

The code stop before the beforeinstallprompt and the code inside it is not executed.

Here is my code in my service:

```
  initPwaPrompt(): void {
    if (this.platform.ANDROID) {
      window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (event: any) => { 
        event.preventDefault();
        this.promptEvent = event;
        this.openPromptComponent('android');
      });
    }
    if (this.platform.IOS) {
      const isInStandaloneMode = ('standalone' in window.navigator) && (window.navigator['standalone']);
      if (!isInStandaloneMode) {
        this.openPromptComponent('ios');
      }
    }
  }
```

the code doesn't reach the code inside the `window.addEventListener` it's like the listener is not even attached...
while if i put the openPrompt after the `if (this.platform.ANDROID) {` the popup is shown property..

EDIT:

I've yet tried to clear site data and to use a different device.

Comment: The issue was that i had in my index.html registered two manifest, one of which was manifes.json which was the old one, so the beforeinstallprompt wasn't firing as the old Service Worker was not registered correctly.